# ag-grid Angular - How to customize the column via Markup/HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular10

I am new to `ag-grid` and planning to implement that for our Angular project. It looks great except it's support for ***cell templating***. Unlike `PrimeNG` or `Devextreme` I don't see a "templating" feature for the column.

Most of the documentation of ag-grid explains how to customize the cell via "cellrenderer" in component.ts class. I want to customize the cell via html instead of .ts

Below code is part of `PrimeNG` to customize the cell via template. Can someone help me to implement the same in `ag-grid` via html

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
        <tr>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td><img [src]="'assets/showcase/images/demo/product/' + product.image" [alt]="product.name" width="100" class="p-shadow-4" /></td>
            <td>{{product.price | currency:'USD'}}</td>
            <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            <td><p-rating [ngModel]="product.rating" [readonly]="true" [cancel]="false"></p-rating></td>
            <td><span [class]="'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()">{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an angular component instead of just plain text. You can do this using `cellRendererFramework` that you can access from the column definition.

```
{
          headerName: "CLIENT",
          field: "client",
          cellRendererFramework: (params) => {
            return <AgGridCellRenderer>
              
            </AgGridCellRenderer>
          },
        },
```

the `params` argument has all the agRid stuff like ´api`and`columApi` as well as the original cell value as well as the entire row data.

Comment: Thanks, Let's say I have 15 columns which needs to be customized then do I need to create 15 components and map that to cell renderer? I feel like it wont be clean in terms of code maintenance. I expect to put everything in single html? is't possibile?

Comment: you can create a function that takes the params of the cellRendererFramework and then switches on the columnId (you can find it as `params.colDef.colId`) it will return a specific component. then for each column Definition you just set cellRendereFramework to that function.